# Package 'libxslt' not found though installed in machine [FEDORA]

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, dnf

I'm trying to run a `cmake` command (`sudo cmake -S. -B./build -G Ninja`).

This gives me the error:

```bash
-- Configuring FOSSOLOGY
-- Checking for module 'libxslt'
--   Package 'libxslt', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:607 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/SetDefaults.cmake:127 (pkg_check_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (include)
```

But when I run `yum list installed | grep libxslt`, I get the following output:

```bash
libxslt.x86_64                                    1.1.37-1.fc37                      @fedora
```

Also, running `sudo dnf install libxslt` says:

```bash
Package libxslt-1.1.37-1.fc37.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
```

However running `which libxslt` says:

```bash
libxslt not found
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `libxslt-devel` package which includes the header files needed for compilation.